# Zooming out on Browser causes styling issues

Tags: html, css, browser, zooming, stylesheet

When zooming out on Firefox (and most other browsers), the layout of the right side-bar and the top menu breaks. The side-bar jumps to the bottom of the page. To replicate this issue, please [visit the site](http://the-artifice.com/death-note-morality/) and:

1. Find `Zoom Out` under the browser view menu and click it a few times.
2. Pay attention to how it affects the menu and the sidebar.

The only solution that I found to this so far is to decrease the width of the sidebar with a few pixels and decrease the width of one of the menu list items. The problem with this *dummy* fix is that when the site is viewed on actual size, then it is visible that the menu is missing a few pixels on the width.

Surely, there must be a better solution to this issue. Do you know?

Comment: It's happening in chrome as well.

Comment: In Safari too (when zoomed out twice).

Comment: IE 10 too (When zoomed out at least once)

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, desktop browsers do not use subpixel-resolution for layouts (WebKit does currently have an implementation pending, but no word on other browser engines). That's the reason why you can't use fractions of a pixel when sizing boxes in CSS. Zooming only scales the CSS properties by a common zoom factor and the rounds off the remainder (I'm guessing it floors the values) so that the layout engine can work with integers instead of floating point numbers.

There is no hard solution to this apart from trying to pick pixel values that divide evenly between the zoom levels. Another approach would be to use a percentage-based width definition for the containers – that way, the browser will round off the numbers correctly for you and if the common width of both containers never exceeds 100% (you might need to subtract a tenth or hundreth of a percent due to rounding), you should be good to go on all zoom levels.

This is not to be confused with CSS3 scaling, which does allow you to scale arbitrarily (and indeed can result in edges that do not align to the screen pixels), since this does not affect layout in any way.

*EDIT:* Example: size the columns using percentages

```
#left-area { width: 66.3179%; /* 634/956 */ }
#right-area { width: 33.6820%; /* 322/956 */ }
```

Comment: Interesting respond. The problem is that, why do other sites not have the same issue? I have checked their source and not all sites use percentages for their divs. There must be something that they are doing correctly...?

Comment: IS OP using fractions of a pixels anywhere?

Comment: Can't answer that conclusively, since there's a lot of possibilities like leaving margins between neighbouring columns which avoids summing up container widths to above the width of the parent. Basically, be aware that floating point errors will create overshooting when summing up numbers, which causes the collapse in your case. Leave a 2-pixel gap between the columns, for example.

Comment: Fractions of pixels? Do you mean, if I add decimals to the dimensions? No. The only time that I have done that is on font styling but that should not affect anything.

Comment: @KrofDrakula If I understand your solution correctly, are you saying that I should add a 2 pixel 'margin' between each column? And in this case, also add 2 pixel margin to the menu list items?

Comment: @Misagh You can try floating columns left and right and just specify the width of one minus 2 pixels so they sum up as 2 pixels short of their parent width. That way you sidestep the rounding error.

Comment: @KrofDrakula Can you kindly update your answer with this solution (with example code) so that I understand it. Sorry about the confusion.

Comment: @Misagh I've added the example using percentages, appears not to break while zooming out in Chrome/Windows.

Comment: Cheers for the update. Two questions remains, do you know the compatibility of width percentages (using four decimals!)? And my second question is regarding the menu itself. How would you calculate the width of each menu item? Considering that width difference depends on the name of the menu and also, it is using a custom font meaning that on some browsers, the width will differ.

Comment: Read my Script Junkie article on CSS units: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj687762.aspx As far the variable width is concerned, consider using max-width to constrain it to a maximum width. There is no general solution to that problem, rather something that needs to be built into the design.

Comment: I just read your article. It is awesome! I liked that you used "Bayes" in one of the examples. Statistics is fun ;o)

Answer (score 0):

For the top menu, you can try setting the `div` wrapping the two `ul`'s to `position:relative`, and then set the `ul#mega` element to `position:absolute` with an additional CSS declaration of `right:0`.  Absolute positioning seems to be a good cross-browser way of fixing issues like this.

For the sidebar, you can set `position:absolute` and `right:0` to `div#sidebar`.

*Thought process 1 for Safari issue:*

If the 'more' menu width is different in the top menu, try setting `ul#secondary-menu` to `position:relative;z-index:11;`.  Then, you can add padding-left to the `li.mmore` child of `ul#mega` to compensate for different browser width evaluations at different zooms by sweeping the `li` under the other `li`'s, so to speak. Then, to widen the colored line, transfer `border-bottom` declarations from the `a` child of `li.mmore` to `li.mmore` itself and adjust the height accordingly.

Comment: Ah, I only noticed the "more" menu item... OK, well setting position:absolute and right:0 to div#sidebar works too.  Only tested on Chrome, though

Comment: @moonDogDog Which div are you referring too (that is wrapping the two ul's)? Tried this in Firebug but didn't work for me, but I may have done it wrong...

Comment: To confirm, for 'div#second-menu', you added 'position:relative' and then for 'ul#mega' you added 'position:absolute' and 'right:0'. And finally for the 'div#sidebar', you added 'position:absolute' and 'right:0'?

Comment: Yes.  I am currently on Firefox 14 and have updated to 17, which works as expected.  What exactly are you seeing after said styles are applied?

Comment: @moonDogDog I just tested this and it works. Only one issue: On Safari, when you zoom out, a space is added between the MORE menu button and the rest of the content. The space is not added on Firefox. Do you have a fix for this? You might be able to replicate it in other browsers than Safari too.

Comment: @moonDogDog You are the closest so far with a workable fix, so fingers crossed that you will resolve this last bit.

Comment: You may have to hide that last li under the other li's.  Just a thought:  maybe combine the li's into one parent ul instead of using two ul's and then nest the popup inside the last li?

Answer (score 0):

When you resize the browser the pixel values are necessarily rounded, and this is leading to a  problem where the `sidebar` and `left-area` don't have enough room to fit side-by-side, and you can see it drops to the bottom of the page.

The width of the `main-content` is 956px, `left-area`: 634px, `sidebar`: 322px.

634 + 322 = 956.

When you zoom in, the values are

633 + 321 = 954 > 953

Any hardcoded pixel values are going to have this rounding problem, consider using percents.

Comment: I may be incorrect here, but as far as I have seen, most websites that use more than one column set their dimensions in hardcoded pixels...? While I completely understand the logic that you presented in your answer, I am questioning if the main cause of this is the use of hardcoded pixels and more importantly, if the only solution is to use percentages.

Answer (score 0):

in head tag try giving something like this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=0.47, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=1">
```

Comment: <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=0.47, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=1">